# user input array reversing in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to take input from user and store them in an array, and reverse the array.

For example: if I type "i am a beginner", it have to show,"rennigbe a ma i". here is my code.

The only problem in this code is that it only reverses a string, not the full array.

For example, I typed, "windows". it shows "swodniw". but when I typed,"i am a beginner", it only shows "i".

Why is that? I am not familiar with bash. Please help me out.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "type:"
read -a input
for a in ${input[@]}
do 
echo "you typed:$a"
done

len=${#input}
for (( i=$len-1; i>=0; i-- ))
do
    reverse="$reverse${input:$i:1}"
done

echo "$reverse"
```

Comment: Why not just use [`rev`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rev.1.html)?

Comment: no, i can't use rev. i have to do this by loop. thank you.

Comment: You are only reading the first element of the array. Try `echo $input` and see what you get.

Comment: @123, thank you.. i got my answer.. i just remove the "-a" and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You read into an array, but then only process the first element. You need another loop.

TBH, it would be a lot easier just to remove `-a`.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to use `rev` . However, IF you are not limited to arrays.Awk can be used.

```
echo windows | awk -v FS="" '{for(i=NF;i>=1;--i) if(i==1) printf $i"\n";else printf $i }'
swodniw

    echo "i am a beginner" | awk -v FS="" '{for(i=NF;i>=1;--i) if(i==1) printf $i"\n";else printf $i }'
    rennigeb a ma i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "type:"
read -a input
for a in ${input[@]}
do 
echo "you typed:$a"
done

rev<<<${input[@]}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.  In particular, this question probably wants an array of reversed items, rather than just dumping them to standard outupt.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the requirement, it sounds like you need to reverse a *string*, not an *array*. `"i am a beginner"` looks an awful lot like a bash string, although it would be possible to represent it as an array of strings, e.g. `declare -a array_of_strings=(I am a beginner);` stores an array with one string per word, or even an array of single-char strings, e.g. `declare -a array_of_chars=('i' ' ' 'a' 'm' ' ' 'a' ' ' 'b' 'e' 'g' 'i' 'n' 'n' 'e' 'r');` stores an array with one string per char.

The behavior of the `read` builtin when given the `-a` option is to split the input line on whitespace (more precisely, taking the chars in `$IFS` as delimiting characters) and store the resulting words in the named array variable. Hence you'll get the equivalent of `$array_of_strings` I showed in the previous paragraph.

The problem with this representation of the input is that you have to iterate through both the array words and the characters within each word. This will require two loops.

Other notes:

- For an array variable named `input` the correct syntax to retrieve the number of elements in the array is `${#input[@]}`. The syntax `${#input}` merely retrieves the string length of the first element of the array, which is not what you want.
- When using the `read` builtin, you're probably going to want to pass the `-r` option to prevent backslash interpolation of the input.
- When using the `read` builtin, if you want a prompt, you should use the `-p` option for a fixed prompt to the left of the cursor.

So here's how we can implement this task using arrays and a double loop:

```
read -r -p 'type: ' -a input;
for a in "${input[@]}"; do
    echo "you typed:$a";
done;

inputRev=();
for ((i = ${#input[@]}-1; i >= 0; --i)); do
    word="${input[i]}";
    wordRev='';
    for ((j = ${#word}-1; j >= 0; --j)); do
        wordRev+="${word:j:1}";
    done;
    inputRev+=("$wordRev");
done

echo "${inputRev[@]}";
```

Demo (with the script named `script2`):

```
./script2 <<<'i am a beginner';
## you typed:i
## you typed:am
## you typed:a
## you typed:beginner
## rennigeb a ma i
```

But, as I said earlier, it would make more sense to work with a string rather than an array. Here's how we can implement that:

```
read -r -p 'type: ' input;
echo "you typed:$input";

inputRev='';
for ((i = ${#input}-1; i >= 0; --i)); do
    inputRev+="${input:i:1}";
done

echo "${inputRev[@]}";
```

Demo (with the script named `script3`):

```
./script3 <<<'i am a beginner';
## you typed:i am a beginner
## rennigeb a ma i
```

---

Response to your comment: When you *only* remove the `-a` from your code, the behavior of the script follows a bit of a fusion of my two demos. Let me explain. First, the removal of the `-a` causes bash to read the entire line (minus any leading/trailing whitespace) into `$input` as a string variable, *not* an array variable. This is like my second demo. And because the final loop in your code is equivalent to the final loop in my second demo, the reversal works perfectly and identically, processing `$input` as a string variable.

The reason why the `you typed:` output lines appear the same between your `-a`-removed code and my first demo is that you have not expanded the `$input` string variable correctly in your initial for-loop. You have used `${input[@]}`, which is how you are supposed to expand array variables when you are willing to allow word-splitting to take effect on them. When you *don't* want word-splitting to take effect on an array variable, you should double-quote the expansion, i.e. `"${input[@]}"`. But here, since `$input` is a string variable you shouldn't be using either form. Instead, you should expand it as `"$input"`, which is how to expand a string variable without word-splitting. Also, note that failing to double-quote the expansion, i.e. `$input`, would result in word-splitting just like `${input[@]}`. And the reason why your use of `${input[@]}` worked the same way `$input` would work is that when you try to expand a string variable as an array variable, it simply expands to the string value, identical to how `$input` works.

Comment: if i just remove -a from my code, i got same answer as your 1st demo.. why is that? And also thank you for nice explanation..